# Multiple Projects in a Git Repository

Tags: git

I have a core project (a web app) that has several related services that go along with it.

These services all read off the core project's database, so it is essential that whenever the db schema is changed, all of the projects must be updated. Sometimes when a new feature is added to the core, a few of the services need to be changed as well, but often this is not the case. These services are tightly integrated with the DB schema and are not reusable in other applications.

Further, there is another project that is just a native OS app skin on the core web app project with a slightly reduced feature set (so it is not true that any new feature put in the core web app must appear in the native app). However, it will certainly have to be updated whenever a db schema change happens.

What is the recommended way to structure a git repo(s) around a project like this? I was thinking the core project and the services should exist in one repo together, but then it feels weird also having the native app in there as well (by that logic, when we get an iPad app, then that would go there too?? Seems like a huge messy repo at that time).

One thing to keep in mind is that I want to stay away from any complex workflows since many people are not familiar with git.

Answer (score 0):

> One thing to keep in mind is that I want to stay away from any complex workflows since many people are not familiar with git.

In that case, frankly, I'd suggest that you just keep everything in the same repository.  While submodules have become easier to use as git has continued to develop, they're still a very common source of confusion for people who are new to git.

If you're careful to exclude generated and large binary files from your repository, you'll probably barely notice the extra space / bandwidth used by having a repository that also contains the iPad app, etc., since git's object storage is very efficient.

Comment: how would your answer be different if you were dealing with a team of people used to git?

Comment: @Jarrod Everett: Well, you *could* create a repository just containing the db schema and db migrations, and add that as a submodule to each different project.  I'd still be inclined to keep them all in a single repository, but don't know enough details to know whether that would be sensible - e.g. if some code should be made public, but some should not, then that would strongly suggest making them separate projects.